# How to migrate sql server compact edition 4.0 database to sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

How to migrate  sql server compact edition 4.0 database to sql server express? i am learning MVC there i created my database in Sql SeverCE now i want to migrate it in Sql Express.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Going from Compact to Express Edition should be as simple as scripting the structures and database objects and recreating them on the SQL Express Edition Instance. It should be straight forward since Express supports more code than Compact. Most people encounter problems going from Express to Compact, not vice versa because Compact Edition has a restricted coding model.

In SSMS 2008, you also have the option to Script Data under the Table/View Options of the Scripting Wizard, so you can easily migrate the data using the built in Scripting Wizard in SSMS 2008 as well. To open the Scripting Wizard, right click on the database Tasks -> Generate Scripts.